# Sum of all equal entries in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to take the sum of all values where another field is the same ?

I have a table which looks like this :

| id | symbol | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USD | 0.98 |
| 1 | USD | 1.93 |
| 2 | EUR | 2.08 |
| 3 | EUR | 0.42 |
| 4 | USD | 0.18 |

So when I like to only get the list of symbols I do this:

```
select DISTINCT symbol from myTable
```

Which returns me

| id |
| --- |
| EUR |
| USD |

What would I need to do to get a sum of all the rates ?

| id | rates |
| --- | --- |
| EUR | 2,5 |
| USD | 3,09 |

Thanks

Comment: GROUP BY, SUM should do the trick ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT symbol, SUM(rate) AS rates
FROM myTable
GROUP BY symbol;
```